# python speech recognition showing error "module recognition request failed: Internal Server Error"

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, speech-recognition

i was trying to conver voice into text but speech recognisition module throwing internal server error.
this is my code:-

```
import speech_recognition as s 
sr=s.Recognizer()
print("i am your script and listening you...........................")
with s.Microphone() as m:
 audio=sr.listen(m)
 query=sr.recognize_google(audio,language='eng-in')
 print(query)
```

im getting error like:-
`i am your script and listening you...........................
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Believe Itsreal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_*init*_.py", line 894, in recognize_google
response = urlopen(request, timeout=self.operation_timeout)
File "C:\Users\Believe Itsreal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Users\Believe Itsreal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "C:\Users\Believe Itsreal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
response = self.parent.error(
File "C:\Users\Believe Itsreal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "C:\Users\Believe Itsreal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Believe Itsreal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\coding\python_in_hole\python code\api.py", line 6, in 
query=sr.recognize_google(audio,language='eng-in')
File "C:\Users\Believe Itsreal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_*init*_.py", line 896, in recognize_google
raise RequestError("recognition request failed: {}".format(e.reason))
speech_recognition.RequestError: recognition request failed: Internal Server Error
PS D:\coding\python_in_hole> `

i tried to update the module still its not working one of my code on same module was working like a week before but now that code is also not working in this module

Answer (score 0):

What I *suspect* is the problem here is that the `language` parameter being passed to `sr.recognize_google` is incorrect, and is causing the 500 http response.

According to the [documentation for this PyPI module](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/8b07762f80dfec2d34fb4c40b8eddbb7ec503521/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L673), the `language` parameter is an RFC5646 language tag, which takes the format `en-US` or `en-AU`.

Recommend: using the string `en-IN` as your `language` parameter. `eng-in` is not a valid RFC5646 language tag.

Comment: i changed intto en-IN still its not working. 
```import speech_recognition as s 
sr=s.Recognizer()
print("i am your script and listening you...........................")
with s.Microphone() as m:
 audio=sr.listen(m)
 query=sr.recognize_google(audio,language='en-IN')
 print(query)
```


ile "C:\Users\Believe Itsreal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error